# ASP.Net WebApi responding unauthorized acess

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I am having `ASP.Net webapi` which is hosted on Azure. Actually I am having `two different subscription`

1. For Azure Active Directory - say its `demo.onmicrosoft.com`
2. For hosting webapi. - say its hosted on `abc.azurewebsites.net`

My api which is hosted on `abc.azurewebsites.net` is registered on `demo.onmicrosoft.com`. My client app is a service app which is authenticating against a user that resides in `demo.onmicrosoft.com`. Authentication is basic authentication by passing user credentials and recieveing `AccessToken` from `Azure Active Directory`. After recieving token from `demo.onmicrosoft.com` I am calling api from `abc.azurewebsites.net`. Like this:

`https://abc.azurewebsites.net/api/some/queryapi`

Now, In my controller if I use

```
[Authorize]
public class SomeController:ApiController
{
  //my code
}
```

I am getting uauthorized access. and if I remove that attribute from controller it works fine. 
Can you help me out.Even after app registration & authentication why I am getting so. Is that because of two different subscription or something else.

### Update

I am sending token to my webapi this way

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);
}
```

IMO, since my token is from azure ad of some other subscription so its not getting recognized by my webapi.

### More Update - Startup.cs

```
  public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                         ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                    },
                });
        }
```

Web.config

```
  <add key="ida:Tenant" value="demo.onmicrosoft.com" />
  <add key="ida:Audience" value="https://demo.onmicrosoft.com/4e4xxxx5-5xx1-4355-8xxc-705xxxx163" />
  <add key="ida:ClientID" value="d0xxxxa-2xxx6-4xx-9e58-07xxxxxxxx1" />
```

Comment: are you sure that the accessToken is in the header of the request?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi yes, with every post and get request, i am sending token.

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi see update.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct access token? The access token you use for the API should be one that Azure AD has given for the purpose of calling the API. Also how have you setup Azure AD Bearer token authentication on the API?

Comment: as FEI's answer, the problem is related to Startup.cs. Check the value for Audience.

Answer (score 2):

It is relative to how you protect the web API instead of Azure subscription. For example, here is a piece of code which used to protect web API using Azure AD in the .net core:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
        // Add the console logger.
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);

        // Configure the app to use Jwt Bearer Authentication
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            Authority = String.Format(Configuration["AzureAd:AadInstance"], Configuration["AzureAD:Tenant"]),
            Audience = Configuration["AzureAd:Audience"],
            Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnTokenValidated = tokenValidated ,
                OnAuthenticationFailed= AuthenticationFailed
            }
        });
}
```

This web API will verify the signature of the token to ensure the token is issued from Azure AD. Then it will check the `aud` claim in the access token. If the `aud` claim also matched as we config in above code the we can call the web API successfully.

Comment: Thanks , i will look into my startup file and let you guys know.

Comment: What's the `aud` in the access token? You can get `aud` claim by parsing the access token from [here](https://jwt.io/).

Comment: @AmitRanjan Have you fixed this issue? Please feel free to let me know if you still have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1). Make sure Azure Authentication setting off.

2). In StartupAuth.cs

```
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            // Note: Remove the following line before you deploy to production:
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

follow this article: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api